# Groups question, how can i solve it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Among 100 students in the undergraduate computer science and mathematics, 43 are enrolled in algebra, 52 are enrolled in statistics and 30 are not enrolled in either algebra or statistics on. How many students are enrolled simultaneously in algebra and statistics?

Comment: This is nothing to do with groups - in mathematics, 'group' means something quite different and more specific than in the English language!

Answer (score 1):

100-30 = 70 students are enrolled in either algebra, statistics or both.

70 = People in algebra + People in statistics - people in both (you don't count them twice)

$70 = 43 + 52 - x$

$x = 95 - 70 = 25$